# HDMI not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: hdmi

If I connect my TV with my laptop with a HDMI cable, my TV displays only the desktop even if on the laptop I see something else. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try pulling windows over the edge of your laptop display? I guess they are configured as "next to each other"

Comment: You are right, they don't have the same resolution I think. If I drag the window of any program to the right - bottom corner of my laptop's monitor I can see it on the left - top corner of my TV's display. How can I fix it without dragging manually every window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *System Settings* > *Hardware* > *Displays*
There you can set anything related to display resolution, orientation, placement related to each other, "next to each other"/"clones", etc...

Comment: Thanks, I solved it now, but I have one more problem: the sound is still on the laptop, how can I switch it to the TV?

Comment: It depends on whether both your PC and TV support audio transmission via HDMI (I've heard not all do) Click the speaker-icon in the panel and select *Audio settings* If both devices support it, you may select the audio device that should be used in the appearing dialog.